# CMakeList - how to patch source with older cmake

Tags: cmake

I have source code foo_src.tgz. foo_src has a Makefile that needs patching before it can be built. The CMakeLists.txt looks like this:

```
project(foo_prj)
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.17)
enable_language(C ASM CXX)


include_directories(patchtest)

ExternalProject_Add(
        foo
        URL file://${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/patchtest/foo_src.tgz
        URL_HASH MD5=b5f0cf41a1712d815fdc6ad13124f570
        PATCH_COMMAND cmake -E patch < ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/patchtest/fooMakefile.patch
        CONFIGURE_COMMAND ""
        INSTALL_COMMAND cmake -E echo "Skipping install step."
        BUILD_COMMAND make foo CC=${CMAKE_C_COMPILER}
        SOURCE_DIR patchtest
        STEP_TARGETS build
        EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL TRUE
        BUILD_IN_SOURCE 1
        BUILD_ALWAYS 1)
```

But this gives me a cmake -E command usage error:

```
CMake Error: cmake version 3.8.2
Usage: cmake -E <command> [arguments...]
Available commands: 
.
.
.
```

So it's worth noting that in the usage message of allowable cmake commands, 'patch' is not one of them. The cmake version available in my toolchain in only version 3.8.2. So, how can I go about patching the source with an older cmake?

***edit*** according to [this](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.8/module/ExternalProject.html), the PATCH_COMMAND should be available.

***UPDATE***

Solved this.
First I replaced:

```
PATCH_COMMAND cmake -E patch < ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/patchtest/uio48Makefile.patch
```

with:

```
PATCH_COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E patch < ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/patchtest/uio48Makefile.patch
```

This didn't work, but it did use my local cmake, version 3.17, rather than my toolchain cmake.  This produced the same cmake command usage error though. I then replaced the cmake command in the patch ine like this:

```
PATCH_COMMAND patch < ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/patchtest/uio48Makefile.patch
```

This works! ya....can someone please explain?

Comment: Yes, the `PATCH_COMMAND` keyword exists, but cmake does not know how to perform `cmake -E patch` command. `patch` is not a supported command for `-E` option. Also not in CMake version 3.19.3.

Comment: ahhh that makes sense. I was figuring that cmake was just invoking whatever local patch utility was available. guess not?

Comment: There's  a comment in current documentation https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/ExternalProject.html?highlight=patch_command that reads "By default, no patch command is defined. Note that it can be quite difficult to define an appropriate patch command that performs robustly, especially for download methods such as git where changing the GIT_TAG will not discard changes from a previous patch, but the patch command will be called again after updating to the new tag."

Answer (score 0):

If in our case `patch` works, there might be a working command `patch` in your system, not cmake.

In my case, I don't have `patch`, but I have `git apply` in my system, so I use:

```
PATCH_COMMAND git apply "${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/do-not-build-shared.diff"
```